# Why am I requesting "Device ID & call information" permission on Android?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Testing my Android app (made in Unity) on the live store shows that it requests "Device ID & call information".  As far as I can tell, I don't request these permissions.  Here are the permissions I request in my AndroidManifest.xml file.  Is this a permission required for all apps? Or is it hidden under one of these other permissions?

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Further investigation shows that Unity adds these permissions similar to the question here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/663197/how-to-prevent-unity-from-adding-permissions-to-an.html

Answer (score 3):

I just spent an absurd amount of time trying to resolve this so figured I would share with anyone out there going through a similar agony.

Removing the permissions from your manifest will not necessarily remove them from the final build. Unity auto-detects required permissions from all included libraries. The libraries which are most likely causing you to have this permission included are from the Facebook sdk.

If you want to keep the Facebook sdk in the build, there's a relatively straightforward solution. Remove the Facebook SDK (completely) and install a version <= 7.80. For whatever reason, the changes to the sdk in 7.9+ prompt Unity to auto-include the READ_PHONE_STATE permission which triggers the Device ID & Call Information permission warning in google play.

Comment: That's a very good insight. I was searching for a similar question but for me adding firebase analytics and crashlytics seems added these extra permission request.