# Android: Why I my app is asking for Device ID & Call information on PlayStore

Tags: android

My app is asking for Device ID & Call information where as I have not request it in Manifest file. Please Help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:largeHeap="true" package="com.anakooter.mehndidesigns"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" android:name=".SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_gallery" android:name=".GalleryActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_slider" android:name=".SliderActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25089311/1777090)

Comment: A little more detail about the problem wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that you are using Eclipse for your IDE.

In that case, please add [a `<uses-sdk>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) with an appropriate `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` to your manifest. Right now, your manifest claims that it should work going back to API Level 1 (Android 1.0) and that you were thinking of API Level 1 when you wrote the code. These cause your app to request certain permissions automatically, for backwards-compatibility reasons.